# how to subtract 2 hours and convert to minutes in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 time columns with `hh:mm` format in my oracle database. I want to get the difference between this time format and to convert the output of this in to minutes.

I have tried the following but its not working:

```
select ( d.to_time - d.from_time )  
from DEPT d;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the *actual* datatype of the `TO_TIME` and `FROM_TIME` columns?

Is it `VARCHAR2`?  `DATE`?  `TIMESTAMP`?

I suspect it's `VARCHAR2`.  If so, you could do something like this:

```
select (to_date(to_char(trunc(sysdate),'YYYY-MM-DD')||' '||d.to_time),'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI') 
     - to_date(to_char(trunc(sysdate),'YYYY-MM-DD')||' '||d.to_time),'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI'))*1440
  from my_tab d;
```

Comment: Its VARCHAR2. and i have tried this but the to_time is not properly concating with the system date. showing error ORA-01898: too many precision specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more promising,

```
SELECT (to_date( TO_CHAR(to_date(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
  ||' '
  ||d.to_time) ,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI') - to_date( TO_CHAR(to_date(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
  ||' '
  ||d.from_time) ,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI')) *1440 as conv_min
FROM dept_opd_schedule_det d;
```